# R - Logistf vs glm vs clogit for studies with matched pairs

Tags: r, matching, glm, logistic-regression, logistf

I'm working on a database with matching pairs (1 to 5/6 matching) and am trying to obtain the Odds Ratio (95% confidence interval) for my variables using conditional logistic regression.

```
G1_LR<-glm(formula=MCM.POSS~factor(AED1TRIM_EXP)+factor(BMI)+factor(FOLIC_ACID),family=binomial(),data=G1)
summary(clogit((MCM.POSS)~factor(AED1TRIM_EXP)+factor(BMI)+factor(SMOKING)+factor(FOLIC_ACID)+strata(BABY_PATID),data=G1))**
```

Thereafter, I found that that two of my predictor variables had a quasi-complete separation so I decided to try the penalized maximum likelihood estimation method (logistf).

```
G1_edited<-logistf(formula=MCM.POSS~factor(AED1TRIM_EXP)+factor(BMI)+factor(SMOKING)+factor(FOLIC_ACID),family=binomial(),data=G1)
```

However, two problems emerged. Firstly, the odds ratio(95% confidence interval obtained from the `logistf` command (`OR = 0.9`) differed widely from the clogit and glm command (OR = 3.0). Secondly, I tried but failed to include the `strata()` function (like what I did in the clogit command to account for matching pairs in my cond. logistic regression) to the `logistf` command so I suspect that the `OR = 0.9` obtained is incorrect because it did not compare my cases to its respective 5/6 controls.

Is there an explanation for the differences in OR obtained and is there a way for me to include the `strata()` function to my `logistf` command? Thank you very much in advance!

PS: I'm new to R so please let me know if the problem wasn't clearly expressed  or if you need any further clarification.

Comment: Doing `library("sos"); findFn("{conditional logistic}")` finds some useful stuff, including lasso/penalized conditional logistic ...

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for the advice, appreciate it. I tried the penalised conditional logistic command `clogitL1` but it did not work so I think I'll just report the log likelihood ratio and merge categories within a variable to prevent the quasi-complete separation. Read it on a paper titled Convergence Failures in Logistic Regression  by Paul D. Allison